# Accept payment for digital goods

Tags: merchants

I want to accept Monero for a digital good I am selling but I am new to the crypocurrency and I am pretty lost.

I initially thought of using an online wallet such as Cryptonator and MyMonero but I think I will lose money on the transactions between the online wallet and the local wallet (0.02 at Cryptonator and hidden fees at myMonero).

Can I accept payment to my local wallet? Do I have to leave my pc open all day long to accept the payments or it will synch when i get login? Are there any transaction fees when I am using my local wallet?

I don't need automation right now, I assume that the buyer will send me some Monero and a mail and I will be able to trace that user's transaction with my wallet transaction. What information do I have to ask from the buyer to confirm the payment?

I don't have to run this into a Tor because my goods are just software (music sheet editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I accept payment to my local wallet?

Yes, of course.

> Do I have to leave my pc open all day long to accept the payments or it will synch when i get login?

Transactions are stored on the blockchain, your Monero wallet is not needed for them to work. You only need it to check your balance and perform transactions yourself.

> Are there any transaction fees when I am using my local wallet?

No, transaction fees are paid by the sender.

> What information do I have to ask from the buyer to confirm the payment?

You should provide the buyer with a [Payment ID](https://getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/paymentid.html) that lets you identify the transaction.

Comment: I can't identify the correct answer so I mark this as correct answer until other notice. Thank you for your answer, unfortunately i haven't found the right information at the web

Comment: An additional resource is https://globee.com/ .  The founder, Riccardo "fluffypony" Spagni, is a core member of the monero development team https://getmonero.org/community/team/.   Also, they were the folks behind https://www.projectcoralreef.com/ which was an initiative that aimed to, and did do, get an impressive number of big name musical artists to accept monero.  It allows you to accept monero and be paid out in monero, bitcoin, or cash, in varying percentages that you specify.


Edit: All of that information is to say, they're trustworthy.

Comment: Globee is not a resource for my problem is a payment gateway with service fees. I am interested in implementing the solution my own